# How can I get the coordinates of a sprite's position in pygame?

Tags: python, position, pygame, sprite

What' I'm trying to do is prevent my sprite from going off the borders in a game I'm writing.
It should be very simple, here is some pseudo-code of what my program does so far.

```
rect = my_sprite_img.get_rect()
while (1)
    if keydown = left:
        direction = [-30,0]
    elif keydown = right:
        direction = [30,0]
    rect = rect.move(direction)
    screen.blit(mysprite_img, rect)
```

Again, this is not my real code just a super simple example.
All I want to be able to do is to say
"If rect.position.x < 0 : don't move left"
Is there a built in function that gives me the coordinates of a rect, because I haven't been able to find one by looking at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation here:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to
>   move and align the Rect:
>
> ```
> top, left, bottom, right
> topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
> midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
> center, centerx, centery
> size, width, height
> w, h
> ```

So, you can use `rect.left` for the x coordinate, and `rect.top` for the y coordinate. These are attributes, not functions.

Comment: @Timmy you can do the same with `screen` - `screen_rect = screen.get_rect()`; `if rect.left < screen_rect.left:` and `if rect.right > screen_rect.right:`. You can even use it to center `rect` on `screen` - `rect.center = screen_rect.center`